# custom php function dropdown list not working

Tags: php, function, drop-down-menu

I have a form with a input type using a select dropdown which works fine but when i try and put the php code to build the select dropdown into a php function it stops working and i just cannot figure out why. Can anyone show me why it has stopped working.

Working

```
<select name="category" class="form-control">
      <?$categories = $db->select("categories", "deleted = 0 ORDER BY name");
            foreach($categories as $p)
                {?>
                    <option value="<?= $p['id']; ?>"><?= stripslashes($p['name']);?></option>
                <?}?></select>
```

Not Working

```
<?$categories = $db->select("categories", "deleted = 0 ORDER BY name");?>
        <select name="category" class="form-control">
                  <?categoryDropDown($categories);?>
        </select>
```

PHP Function

```
function categoryDropDown($categories)
        {
            foreach($categories as $p)
            {
                $output3 .= '<option value="' . $p['id'] . '">' . stripslashes($p['name']) . '</option>';
            }
        return $output3 ;
        }
```

Comment: If you want to pass an array, you need `[]` in the `name=`. However, this question seems unclear, can you clarify?

Comment: You need to output the results `<?= categoryDropDown($categories);?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `categoryDropDown()` function only `return`s the code needed for your `<option>`s. You need to output it too:

Change:

```
<select name="category" class="form-control">
  <?categoryDropDown($categories);?>
</select>
```

to

```
<select name="category" class="form-control">
  <?= categoryDropDown($categories); ?>
</select>
```

and you should be good to go.